# How to convert a Jquery object to string?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a table using  tag. I'm able to catch the element but not able to convert it into a string and perform the conditional check. Please help!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user tr').each( function(){
           //add item to array
        var value = $(this).find(".user1").html();

        /********* want to do something like 

     if (value == "Y") {
       //apply a class
     }
     *************/

        });
```

Comment: What does the markup look like? What do you end up with in `value` when you try your commented-out code?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (value === "Y") {
    $(this).find(".user1").addClass("a-class");
}
```

Comment: it works under the <div> tag. when trying with .value it catches no value. The code on browser is:-                                 <tbody>
<tr id="myrowKEYSTATSBROKER" class="odd good">
<td class="user" style="width: 175px;" scope="request">
<td class="user1" style="width: 75px;" scope="request"> N </td>
<td style="width: 175px;"> </td>
<td style="width: 100px;">KEYSTATSBROKER</td>
<td style="width: 90px;"> - </td>
<td style="width: 175px;display: none;white-space: nowrap;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">

Comment: `.value` is the property for getting the user-entered input out of `<input type=...`, wrapped by jQuery in `.val()`.  `.html()` is jQuery's wrap of `.innerHTML` property -- the markup nested inside this item.  When I run your sample, I get " N ".

Answer (score 1):

If you need the html, the find returns a collection of results, try to produce a find query very specific and pick the first

```
var html = $(this).find(".user1").first().html();
```

But you can use addClass in this case, is much more effective.

Comment: .first().html() fetches me the value but i'm unable to perform any conditional check over the value I get

Answer (score 1):

Use .get() method of jquery.

```
var value = $(this).find(".user1").get(0);
```

Now u can perform any condition check .

Answer (score 0):

The html() method of jquery only grabs the inner html of an element. The best way to grab the actual html of an element would be to use

```
element.outerHTML;
```

to do that though you have to actually have be manipulating the dom element and not the jquery object.

for example you would do something like this

```
var html = $(this).find(".user1").get(0).outerHTML;
```

That will return *ALL* of the html as a string though, including its contents, not just its HTML of the tags. So if you just want the element HTML, I would clone the element and empty its HTML content.

```
var tag = $(this).find(".user1").clone().html('').get(0).outerHTML;
```

Comment: .outerHTML fetches no value in my case.